# Docker COPY failed on gitignored file on Github Action

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I am as novice as it comes to Docker and have just been through stuff at the wall until it sticks. But now I'm stuck.

I have the following folder structure in my project

```
project
 ┣ .github
 ┃ ┗ workflows
 ┃ ┃ ┗ deploy.yml
 ┣ server
 ┃ ┣ Dockerfile
 ┗ web
```

My `Dockerfile` in `./server` is as follows

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .
COPY .env.production .env

RUN yarn build

ENV NODE_ENV production

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
USER node
```

Amongst other things, I am trying to copy the contents `.env.production` into a new file `.env`. But `.env.production` only exists in my local directory as it exists in my `.gitignore` file.

So running

```
docker build -t <username>/<projectname>:<version> .
```

works fine locally, but not when I try to run it on a github action, I get the following error

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat .env.production: file does not exist
```

I also tried to use `docker/build-push-action@v3`

But I was getting a similar error

```
buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref "/.env.production": not found
```

My `deploy.yml` file is as follows

```
name: Deploy Application

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./server

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.13.0]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Node Version ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: "yarn"
          cache-dependency-path: "./server/yarn.lock"
      - name: Publish docker image
        run: |
          docker login --username ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }} --password '${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}'
          docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}/${{ secrets.DOCKER_REPOSITORY }}:1 .
```

What's the best solution to get my environment values from my local `.env.production` file (without exposing it) and copy to an `.env` file?

Comment: I don't think you need the `setup-node` action

Comment: What do you mean "without exposing it"? Does your `.env.production` contain secrets? If not, remove it from your .gitignore. If it does, then your question becomes "how to manage secrets in a docker-based node project"

Comment: My workflow is larger than what I have above that relies on node, so I do need it in this scenario. It does contain secrets, which is why I can't expose it, but I did find a solution of generating the file via GitHub Actions using GitHub Action secrets are the environment variables values so they do not get exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for using `SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3` to create the `.env.production` file when running the workflow and using GitHub Action secrets are the environment variables values so they do not get exposed.

```
- name: Create .env.production file
  uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3
  with:
    envkey_SESSION_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SESSION_SECRET }}
    directory: ./server/
    file_name: .env.production
    fail_on_empty: false
```